# How to make an algorithm to get all column names from across tables that relations with their primary key in SQL Server and C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, algorithm

I have 3 tables (for example 3, but in real over than 30 tables with this conditions) in my SQL Server database: post, user, person.

- `post`: (post_id, post_text, user_id)
- `user`: (user_id, user_name, person_id)
- `person`: (person_id, person_phone, person_email)

Now, in C#, I want an algorithm that creates a query that get result like this:

```
post.post_id, post.post_text, post.user_id, user.user_id, user.user_name, user.person_id, person.person_id, person.person_email
```

and I use this method for fill a `SqlDataReader` in C# for reading and accessing all column values from these records.

I know that the common way to get that result directly and manually using of 'Join' statement, but it is waste time if tables count is very much. So, I want an algorithm that generates this query for manipulate in C# programming.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site. Try for yourself and ask questions about a specific problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

To query all column names from your tables, you can use:

```
SELECT obj.Name + '.' + col.Name AS name
FROM sys.columns col 
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj 
ON obj.object_id = col.object_id 
WHERE obj.Name IN ('post', 'user', 'person')
ORDER BY name
```

Then, for how to call this from C# using SqlDataReader, you can use this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

select post1.post_id, post1.post_text, post1.user_id, user1.user_id, user1.user_name, user1.person_id, person1.person_id, person1.person_email from post post1 inner join user user1 on user1.user_id=post1.user_id inner join person person1 on person1.person_id=user1.person_id